# insert middleware before database access in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model called `Project` in Rails, and it has a text field `title`. In my existing Rails application, I have many places where I read from the database to retrieve `project.title`. Now, I'm able to encrypt the `title` before saving it, so I would need a way to decrypt the value after retrieving from database, before presenting it to the app layer (controller or view). Is there a way in Ruby on Rails to do so, instead of inserting a decrypt function before every `project.title`?

Comment: You mean like cache, maybe?

Comment: would it scale? I mean, if I have a thousand projects by different users. I would need to cache all the `project.title`s?

Comment: This really sounds like it should be done on the model layer. Middleware is for pre/post-processing requests. This is like using a bulldozer to do carpentry.

Comment: can I simply use `after_save` in my model to perform decryption?

Comment: Well not if you want to use the decrypted title after fetching records from the database. For that you would need a different callback. I would really take a look at the [attr_encrypted gem](https://github.com/attr-encrypted/attr_encrypted) and if not use it then at least learn the gist of how to approach the problem.

Comment: Looks like this gem works for my use case. I'm now able to transparently encrypt in database without needing to change application code. Thanks!